# Is there a way to improve performance of Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

I am using autodesk forge viewer to load models which have multiple views. But i have hard time rendering all the elements on the viewer of the model. The progress bar below the viewer is always loading. Is there a way to increase the performance of the viewer except using headless browser.

Comment: Could you share more details about what kind of models you're trying to load aggregately, building projects, rebars?

Comment: a revit model, with multiple views containing multiple models and 2D pdsf of building project.
can it be rendered faster in anyways

Comment: Maybe try to load `Autodesk.MemoryLimited` extension to make viewer allocate more memory to load models https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/memory-limit/

Comment: Can u share your code and or model used ? Maybe theres some performance issue in your code

Comment: im very sorry for late reply, i added Autodesk.MemoryLimited extension by upgrading t ver 7, in the documentation it is written as  **Developers and users can validate the feature is in action by verifying that the bottom-left loading bar displays in blue instead of green.**
I can't see blue bar, is it because Autodesk.MemoryLimited extension is not active?

Comment: Maybe this link could solve your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031131/how-to-active-autodesk-memorylimited-extension-in-forge-viewer BR,