# How to active "Autodesk.MemoryLimited" Extension in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm having trouble loading a Large Model in local environment forge viewer.

Already I had check Autodesk Forge Viewer Guide "Allocate Memory for Large Models"(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/memory-limit/)

and I apply "Autodesk.MemoryLimited" Extension in viewer config but anything isn't happened.
Guide document say Developers and users can validate the feature is in action by verifying that the bottom-left loading bar displays in blue instead of green, but loading bar is not changed(still green).

also i load "Autodesk.Viewing.MemoryLimitedDebug" Extension.

Do you have an idea to activate "Autodesk.MemoryLimited" Extension?

[Memory Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTJt9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is missing one small piece of information unfortunately. When using the `Autodesk.Viewing.MemoryLimited` extension you have to configure the actual memory limit you want to impose, for example, like so:

```js
const config = {
    loaderExtensions: { svf: 'Autodesk.MemoryLimited' },
    memory: {
        limit: 1024
    }
};
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'), config);
```

Also, note that the memory-limited loading will *only* be enabled when your model is larger than the configured threshold. If you want to force the memory-limited loading even for smaller models, try this:

```js
const config = {
    loaderExtensions: { svf: 'Autodesk.MemoryLimited' },
    memory: {
        limit: 1024,
        debug: {
            force: true
        }
    }
};
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'), config);
```

#### Edit

The `memory.debug` object can contain additional properties customizing the behavior of the memory-limited loading. Those are meant for internal use but you could experiment with them as well:

```js
options.debug = {
        // Increase the max page out size. On slow (mobile) devices the scene
        // traversal is a bottle neck and making this larger helps load more
        // pack files earlier in the load.
        maxPageOutSize: 195,                                // Max we will page out in one go
        pixelCullingEnable: this.options.onDemandLoading,   // Useful with on demand loading
        pixelCullingThreshold: avp.PIXEL_CULLING_THRESHOLD,

        occlusionThreshold: 1,
        occlusionTestThreshold: 1,
        startOcclusionTestingPackCount: 8,
        testPackfileCount: 4,
        useOcclusionInstancing: true,
        automaticRefresh: true,
        boxProxyMaxCount: 0, // show this many boxes during a render
        boxProxyMinScreen: 0.4 // if entire render batch is >= 1/10 of the screen in area
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer! The Answer is what I need EXACTLY!
After read your answer, i have one more question.
Can i control Memory Manager Debug option such as 'UploadPackfiles'?
In the case of 'Auto Refresh' i add option 'automaticRefresh' to debug Object, It is working.

Comment: Glad we could help! Yes, there are couple more options under `memory.debug`. Those are meant more for internal usage but you could experiment with them as well. Let me add them to the answer.

Comment: When I try to load this extension I'm getting a "Not allowed to load local resource: blob:/xxx" - any idea why?

Comment: Not sure. Is that an error or a warning. If this is something that's actually preventing you from running your viewer app, send us a detailed report to `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we'll look into that.