# Opening larger models on mobile devices using APS viewer (Autodesk.MemoryLimited)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have an Autodesk platform services application that uses the viewer.
I encountered a problem that I can't load large models on iPad.
I tried solving the problem using Autodesk.MemoryLimited extension with limited success.
Is there any documentation for the extension? the only thing I can find was - [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031131/how-to-active-autodesk-memorylimited-extension-in-forge-viewer)

Using the extension in the suggested way:

```
const config = {
    loaderExtensions: { svf: 'Autodesk.MemoryLimited' },
    memory: {
        limit: 1024
    }
};
```

I was able to open the model on IPad pro 12 but not using Ipad 10.
I don't even know what unit is the memory limit, guessing it is MBs I tried changing it to 150, after doing that I wasn't able to open the model in any IPad and in desktop I was able to open the model but didn't really see anything in the viewer.
I am able to open and see the model in BIM360 on IPad 10 so I am guessing it is possible.
Will appreciate any help with better documentation for the extension or an alternative way to open large models.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no documentation for the `Autodesk.MemoryLimited` viewer extension. The extension is only meant to be used with the single `memory.limit` option (yes, it's in MB) as a potential solution in cases where the models are so large that the browser page with the viewer runs out of memory and crashes.

Btw. BIM360, ACC, and other products built on top of Autodesk Platform Services use an optimized format SVF2 instead of the orignal SVF. The SVF2 format optimizes file size, data transfer, and runtime performance as well, so if you're not using it in your workflow yet, I would suggest that you give it a try: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I assumed I was using SVF2 since I opened models from BIM360 but I now believe I was wrong, I think I was missing "env: 'AutodeskProduction2'" from my options when starting the viewer.
This change did help and allow me to open models I previously couldn't, but did not solve the problem and after making this change, the Autodesk.MemoryLimited extension now only did damage (I found somewhere that is doesn't support svf2).
So my question now, is there a way to open large SVF2 models on limited memory devices?