# Forge MemoryLimited

Tags: memory-management, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Whenever I try to load a model using the MemoryLimited extension, I'm getting:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/xxxxxx
```

I'm loading the extension in the viewer's config options like so Forge v.7.95:

```
const options3d = {
            loaderExtensions: { svf: 'Autodesk.MemoryLimited' },
            memory: {
                limit: 3000
            }
}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Without the extension, the model loads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try reducing the limit or use

```
debug: {
         force: true
       }
```

as mentioned in this answer: [How to active "Autodesk.MemoryLimited" Extension in Forge Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031131/how-to-active-autodesk-memorylimited-extension-in-forge-viewer)

Comment: reducing the limit and adding the force:true still leads to that message in the console and player not loading

Comment: ok, will check and get back to you

Comment: I keep seeing that error in 7.95 and the bar doesn not turn blue

Comment: I am sorry to inform you, this extension is intended for deprecation. May I know what you're trying to achieve, let's explore other solutions. One solution I can think of now is divide the model into multiple models and load and unload on demand.

Comment: How come? It's useful to be able to manage memory, especially on mobile. How will that be handled going forward?

Comment: Please use SVF2 format, it's much better from a memory footprint point of view.